# Creating a table in python

Tags: python, html, list, tuples

I am asking a user to go through a series of questions answer them then there answers will be written to a file called mydoc.doc on the users desktop. The problem I am running into right now is creating a table in Python that creates that creates the same number of rows as the number of interviews the user enters. So if the user enters 5 interviews it asks them 5 times for the start/end time of the interview, the interview type, and the interviewer name (each "interview" is stored in a tuple within a list). It then needs to output each tuple  on one row but each item in the tuple in a different column. I started to play around by putting HTML tags in the code and building a table like that but then how do I tell the program to do 5 rows and to input each one of the things in the tuple in a different column. This is what I have so far..

```
import sys
outfile = open( r'/Users/x/Desktop/myDoc.txt', 'w' )
external = raw_input('is this an exernal invite: ')
inhouse = raw_input('is this an in house invite: ')
if external == 'y'and inhouse== 'y':
    cfname= raw_input('What is the Candidte First Name:')
    clname= raw_input('What is the Candidte Last Name:')
    interviewmonth= raw_input('What is the Month of the interview: ')
    interviewday= raw_input('What is the Day of the interview: ')
    cleadfname= raw_input('What is the recrutiers  first name of the interview: ')
    cleadlname= raw_input('What is the recruiters last name of the interview: ')
    i = 0
    lis = []
    n = int(raw_input("How many interviews are there? "))
    while n:
       i += 1
       istart = raw_input("Interview Start Time: ")
       iend= raw_input("Interview End Time: ")
       ipeople= raw_input("What are the interviewer names: ")
       itype= raw_input("What is the interview type: ")
       lis.append((istart, iend, ipeople, itype))
       n-=1
    a = '<html><head></head><body> Hi %s, </br> The interview is scheduled for <strong>%s %sth</strong>\
         <br/>if you have an questions please contact %s\
         <TABLE border=1>\
         <TR>\
         </TR>\
         <TR>\
         <TH>Interviewer</TH>\
         <TH>Interview Type</TH>\
         </TR>\
         <TR ALIGN="CENTER">\
         <TD>Data 1</TD>\
         <TD>Data 2</TD>\
         </TR>\
         </TABLE>\
         </body></html>'% (cfname, interviewmonth, interviewday, cleadfname)
    outfile.write(a)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Could you show an example: for input X, table Y should be generated?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, use a loop.

First, instead of that dance with i += 1 and n -= 1 and while (n), I suggest
for i in range(n):

Next, once you have your nice lis built up with all the tuples, loop over it.

Here's an example, loosely based on yours but without me having to think up and type in the values. There are a couple of things I query in your code, I have comments in this thing below to ask about them.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

cfname = "Victim"
interviewmonth = "Januember"
interviewday = "Fooday"
cleadfname = "The Boss"

n = 10
lis = []
for i in range(10):
  istart  = "istart  value %d"%i
  iend    = "iend    value %d"%i
  ipeople = "ipeople value %d"%i
  itype   = "itype   value %d"%i
  lis.append((istart, iend, ipeople, itype))

html = """
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <!-- Should have a p tag here -->
    Hi %s, 
    </br>The interview is scheduled for <strong>%s %sth</strong>
    <br/>if you have an questions please contact %s
    <!-- Should have a /p tag here -->
"""
print html%(cfname, interviewmonth, interviewday, cleadfname);

html = """
    <TABLE border=1>
      <TR> <!-- Why'd you have this blank line? -->
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <!-- Didn't understand your headings, should it not be the
             things in lis? 
        -->
        <TH>Start</TH>
        <th>End</th>
        <th>People</th>
        <TH>Interview Type</TH>
      </TR>
"""
print html

# Now here's where I think you want a loop
for interview in lis:
  html = """
      <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s</td>
      </TR>
  """
  print html % interview

html = """
    </TABLE>
  </body>
</html>
"""
print html
```